# Concatenated Select List value returns 'not a valid month' when applied TO_DATE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have month and year values from select list, concatenated them in a string. If TO_DATE is applied on the string, that returns 'not a valid month' error.
Below is my code snippet,

```
V_DATE_FROM_STR_TEST := TRIM('01-'||TRIM(TO_CHAR(:P3_FROM_MONTH))||'-'||TRIM(TO_CHAR(:P3_YEAR)));

V_DATE_TO_STR_TEST := TRIM('01-'||TRIM(TO_CHAR(:P3_TO_MONTH))||'-'||TRIM(TO_CHAR(:P3_YEAR)));
```

Error `'not a valid month'` occurs on this line,

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE(V_DATE_FROM_STR_TEST, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

I have tried printing by `HTP.PRN(V_DATE_FROM_STR_TEST)` that shows date `01-JAN-2020`.

Adding LOVs

**Month LOV**

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1), 'MONTH') d, 
to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1), 'MON') r
  from dual
connect by level <= 12
```

**Year LOV**

```
    select YEAR d, YEAR r
from   (select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -8 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -7 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -6 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -5 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -4 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -3 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -2 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) -1 YEAR
from dual
UNION
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) YEAR
from dual
) order by year desc
```

I am guessing there are some unwanted character is added in the date string from select list value, how can I remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *switch* to digits, things might improve.

Month LoV: display *words*, but return *numbers*:

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1), 'MONTH') d, 
       level r
  from dual
connect by level <= 12;
```

Then use this for the resulting string:

```
to_date(lpad(:P3_FROM_MONTH, 2, '0') || :P3_YEAR, 'mmyyyy')
```

---

Also, all those `TRIM`s look unnecessary, but OK - I understand - you tried to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly referenced you can simplify your "Year LOV" query.

```
select yr d, yr r
  from ( select extract(year from sysdate)-level +1 yr
           from dual 
          connect by level <= 9
       )
 order by yr desc;
```